# Records processed each batch with structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

In the legacy spark streaming there is a metric that you can see how many records are being processed by that particular batch. Is there any way to show something similar in spark structured streaming (3.x.x) metrics?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Structured Streaming Tab shows this.
[image]

See https://databricks.com/blog/2020/07/29/a-look-at-the-new-structured-streaming-ui-in-apache-spark-3-0.html